# Pointer of array pointer objects in QT

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

In C++, I have a array pointer of objects like this:

```
vector<Articulation*> artic;
```

I have the next problem. When I send that vector to another class like &artic. So I have the pointer and not all the array duplicated. The problem is the next. In the new class, i have a ponter of array pointer objects

```
vector<Articulation*>* pArtic;
```

In the new class I do pArtic[i]->move(). The method is implemented in Articulation. When I do the method mov(), QT tell me that the type std::vector<_Ty> dont have an operator ->. That is because, I think, I cant access to the Articulation objects and I am trying to do move() over a vector.

Anyone knows what I must do to acces to the Articulation objects and do the move() method?

Example:

Class A:

```
vector<Articulation*> artic;

void A::initVector(){...}
void A::sendInfoToB(){
B nuevo();
B.send(&artic);
}
```

Class B:

```
vector<Articulation*>* pArtic
void B::send(vector<Articulacion*>* art){
pArtic=art;
}
void B::sendToC()
{
C nuevo();
C->sendTheLast(pArtic);

}
```

Class C:

```
void C::sendTheLast(vector<Articulation*>* artic)
{
string data=artic[i]->move();
//Move returns a String
}
```

That is the example.

Comment: Please provide simple move() method body.

Comment: Can you provide a **small** sample illustrating what you want to do and reproducing the problem? I can't make any sense out of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are calling the method move() of the i-th position of pArtic, which is a pointer to a vector of pointers. What you want to do is calling the method move of the pointer at the position i of the vector.

```
(*pArtic)[i]->move()
```

that is what you want to do, but care, this is not really safe I guess...

a better way would be to give away only the reference `artic` by expecting a `vector<>&` reference, not a pointer.

Comment: I dont understand your solution  :S

Comment: instead of calling `pArtic[i]->move()` you call `(*pArtic)[i]->move()` and it works.

Comment: It works, thanks!! But I have one question, why it works? I dont understand.

Comment: I updated the answer, the first paragraph should explain it... in short: you had a pointer to an array and tried to get the i-th element, but in fact you were looking in the i-th memory cell after the one of the pointer. By dereferencing the pointer (adding *) you do actually get the pointer to the i-th element and can call the method ;)

Answer (score 0):

Store QT objects directly on containers (unless there is a real need of using pointers). This is because QT implements implicit sharing and COW (Copy-On-Write) which eradicates copy-overhead of containers everytime you pass them across. By passing the containers either by value or reference as need be, makes the interface simpler and easy to use.

Again, using raw-pointers in C++ is always dangerous when you have better mechanisms (like smart pointers). Smart pointers makes your program exception safe while managing the life of raw pointers.